# Design an element to have input and send button combined

Tags: html, css

So I stumbled on this task when my designer did the following... I have no idea on how to do this

[image]

My only idea I think is to let the image be a background and then have the input being non-styled, or something... Honestly, I don't know how to solve it, I tried something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
    .formish {
        width: 308px;
        height: 46px;
        background: url('btn2.png');
        background-repeat: none;
        position: relative;
    }

    .formish .btn {
        position: absolute;
        right: 3px;
        top: 1px;
        width: 60px;
        height: 42px;
        border: 0;
        background: none;
        color: none;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form class="formish">
    <input type="email" value="">
    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

It's working sorta, can't get the text field to work properly. Couldn't figure out how to add a image to jsfiddle, so here's the button itself:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are almost there! Just make the email field wider and give it a transparent background color, or just the same light gray as the designer did.

Comment: where is the fiddle link?

Comment: Don't forget to add the default text in the text box
<input type="text" name="inputBox" placeholder="Email">

Answer (score 0):

try something like this,**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kVqc4/2/)**

**CSS**

```
    .formish {
        width: 202px;
        background: red;
        background-repeat: none;
        padding:5px;
    }

    .formish .btn {
        color: white;
        background: transparent;
        border:1px solid white;
    }
    .formish .btn {
        color: white;
        background: transparent;
        border:1px solid white;
    }
    .formish .input {
        border:none;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
 <form class="formish">
    <input type="email" value="" class="input">
    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Send">
</form>
```